# Adjusting multiple text elements in multiple mxd files?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, mxd

I am trying to make changes to titles on multiple mxds instead of having to open 1 by 1 but it is only making changes to 1 mxd file, I have even tried to make duplicate copies of the mxd to test but again it only makes 1 change. The code runs with no issues, am I missing something ?

```
import arcpy, os
from os import listdir

mxdPath = r"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Final Maps\New folder"

mxdFiles = [ f for f in listdir(mxdPath) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mxdPath,f)) and f[-3:] == 'mxd' ]

try:

    map = arcpy.mapping
    for mxdFile in mxdFiles:
        mxd = map.MapDocument(mxdPath + "\\" + mxdFile)
        for elm in map.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT"):
            if elm.text == "CountyProject130":
                elm.text = "Testing709"


    mxd.save()
    del mxd
    Print "Complete!"

except Exception as e:
    print(e.message)
```

Comment: I think that try/except statements are best removed when presenting code here and testing because they can mask otherwise useful messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the formatting is screwed up, you need one more indent when you save the MXD. The way it's showing now only saves the last MXD in the loop.

```
for mxdFile in mxdFiles:
    mxd = map.MapDocument(mxdPath + "\\" + mxdFile)
    for elm in map.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT"):
    |   if elm.text == "CountyProject130":
    |        elm.text = "Testing709"
    |
--->mxd.save()
--->del mxd
```

Comment: GENIUS  ! IT WORKED! Thank you very much !!!!!!!! very very much!